# context.arc(x,y,r,sAngle,eAngle,counterclockwise); can i make this move in the z direction also in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have some random particles. I wanted to position them in 3d space. so far I've been able to place them only in 2d. How can i position them in 3d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas 2D context, where `arc()` is available, is by definition 2D only. To use 3D you would need to use WebGL instead or project 3D coordinates onto the 2D canvas manually.

In both latter options `arc()` won't be available either so you need to manually define the arc using polylines/polygon.

## Example of 3D projection onto 2D canvas

Heavily un-optimized but simplified to show the basics.

```js
// Lets make a basic and simple 3D Point class
 function Point3D(x, y, z) {

   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;

   //rotated coords after using rotation
   this.rx = x;
   this.ry = y;
   this.rz = z;
}

Point3D.prototype = {

  rotateX: function(angle) {
    var rd, ca, sa;
    ca = Math.cos(angle);
    sa = Math.sin(angle);
    this.ry = this.y * ca + this.z * sa;
    this.rz = this.y * sa - this.z * ca;
    return new Point3D(this.rx, this.ry, this.rz)
  },
  
  rotateY: function(angle) {
    var rd, ca, sa;
    ca = Math.cos(angle);
    sa = Math.sin(angle);
    this.rz = this.z * ca - this.x * sa;
    this.rx = this.z * sa + this.x * ca;
    return new Point3D(this.rx, this.ry, this.rz)

  },
  
  rotateZ: function(angle) {
    var rd, ca, sa;
    ca = Math.cos(angle);
    sa = Math.sin(angle);
    this.rx = this.x * ca + this.y * sa;
    this.ry = this.x * sa - this.y * ca;
    return new Point3D(this.rx, this.ry, this.rz)
  },

  project: function(w, h, fov, viewDist) {
    var f, x, y;
    f = fov / (viewDist + this.rz);
    x = this.rx * f + w * 0.5;
    y = this.ry * f + h * 0.5;
    return new Point3D(x, y, this.rz)
  }
}

// create an arc using 3D points
var arc = [];
for(var a = 0; a < Math.PI; a += 0.1) {
  arc.push(new Point3D(Math.cos(a) * 0.8, Math.sin(a) * 0.8, 0))
}

// animate
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
a = 0;

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i = 0, p; p = arc[i++];) {
    // some random rotation and projection (play with the parameters)
    p = p.rotateZ(a*0.1).rotateY(a).rotateX(-a*0.05).project(c.width, c.height, 600, 7);
    i === 0 ? ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y) : ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  
  a += 0.05;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})();
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```